# How to place value at the back of iterated list in for loop?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to write some code that finds the solution to a sudoku puzzle. If a certain solved cell conflicts with the cell the code is currently solving, I want to clear that solved cell and place it at the back of the list I'm iterating over, then try the current cell again. In other words, I want to remove a conflict, postpone solving it and solve the current first.

So far, this is what I have written:

```
def solvepuzzle(grid, input_coordinates):
unsolved_cells = input_coordinates
solved_cells = []

while unsolved_cells:
    for row in unsolved_cells:
        solve(row)

        if solve(row) is True:
           print('Successful')
           unsolved_cells.pop(row)

        if solve(row) is False:
            print('removing conflicting cell..')
            conflicter = find_conflict(grid, row)
            grid = reset_board(grid, conflicter)
            unsolved_cells.append(conflicter)
            unsolved_cells.insert(0, row)

    if not unsolved_cells:
        print('Operation successful.')

if unsolved_cells:
    print('Operation unsuccessful.')
    print('To be made: ', unsolved_cells)

return grid
```

However, this doesn't work as expected. The order of the input_coordinates/ unsolved_cells gets messed up and skips a step, so instead of 1,2,3,4, it just solves for 1,3. Also, I can't seem to make the insert work. The idea is that the for loop will try again if it fails, after the conflict has been erased, but again, the order seems to get randomized.

How can I improve my code?

Comment: You are using `solve` both as a boolean variable and as a function.

Comment: Yes `solve` return a boolean. I print the board later.

Comment: You need to edit the code to something like `if solve(row) == True:`